# How to send JSON-data in post request Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, json

I get an error while I send Json data to server. I used the following code to change the NSMutableDictionary To JSON.

```
NSString* jsonString1 = [postDict JSONRepresentation];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonString1);
```

JSON Format:

```
         {"user_email":"gupta.nivrit@gmail.com","firstname":"nivrit","user_password":"1234","confirm_passward":"1234"}
```

I use the following method to send this JSON format to server:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = 
    (NSMutableDictionary *)[[mWebServiceHelperOBJ 
              makeCallToURL:@"register.php" 
              withDataPost:jsonString1] JSONValue];
```

When I implemented this code I received this issue

```
incompatible pointer type sending  NSString to parameter of type  NSMutableDictionary.
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why you "unaccepted" my answer ...

Answer (score 1):

If your method

```
- (NSString *)makeCallToURL:(NSString*)url withDataPost:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict;
```

is the same as in this question: [Uploading PDF file through JSON Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083111/uploading-pdf-file-through-json-web-service), then the JSON encoding of the request data is done inside 
that method, so you should call it directly with the `postDict`,
and not with the JSON string `jsonString1`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = 
    (NSMutableDictionary *)[[mWebServiceHelperOBJ makeCallToURL:@"register.php" 
                                                   withDataPost:postDict] JSONValue];
```

(This assumes that `postDict` is an `NSMutableDictionary`.)